# Mapping the values from a webhook for PHP

Tags: php, sms, webhooks

How do I map/enter/input values from the webhook?

I'm creating a texting application that will send a text once a meeting is set in our CRM.  As you can see in the below code, we'll be using name, date, time, etc. that's being sent from the CRM.

My terminology is probably way off so any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$accountsid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';// Your AccountSid
$authtoken = 'XXXXXXXXXX';// Your authtoken
$to = 'XXXXXXXXXX'; // Your business call phone you wish to have sms forwarded too
$from =  'XXXXXXXXXX'; // Your Message360 number
$content = "Hi ".$_POST[host].", this is just a reminder that we have a meeting scheduled for ".$_POST[time]." at ".$_POST[location]."";//content of the SMS
$tocountrycode = 1;
$fromcountrycode = 1;



                    $url = "https://api.message360.com/api/v2/sms/sendsms.xml";
                    $username = $accountsid;
                    $password = $authtoken;

                    $post = array(
                            'body' => $content,
                            'to' => $to, 
                            'from' => $from,
                            'tocountrycode' => $tocountrycode,
                            'fromcountrycode' => $fromcountrycode);
                    $ch = curl_init();

                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($post));
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

                    $post_response = curl_exec($ch);

                    // Checks for Errors
                    if (curl_errno($ch) > 0)
                    {
                                   $error = curl_getinfo($request);
                                   echo "ERROR: <BR>";
                                   print_r($error);
                        $_SESSION['curl_error'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
                        $_SESSION['gnc_order_error'] = TRUE;
                    }
                        curl_close($ch);
                        exit;
                        ?>
```